# Is boost_asio_handler_invoke_helpers::invoke still a supported way to invoke completion handler in boost asio 1.70?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am migrating a code using asio from boost 1.65.1 to 1.70.0. 
There is a code that use boost_asio_handler_invoke_helpers::invoke and it seem not working as in previous version.

I found this issue https://github.com/boostorg/asio/issues/79 on github which explain how executor_binder works. So It seems the old asio_handler_invoke function won't work anymore in this case.

```cpp
class callback_service {
public:
    void run() {
        if (callback_) callback_();
    }

    void subscribe(std::function<void(void)> callback) {
        callback_ = std::move(callback);
    }

private:
    std::function<void(void)> callback_;
};

template <typename CompletionToken>
auto async_wait_callback(callback_service& service, CompletionToken&& token)
{
    return boost::asio::async_initiate<CompletionToken, void(void)>(
        [] (auto&& completion_handler, callback_service& s) {
            s.subscribe([h=std::move(completion_handler)] () mutable {

                // Is this still worked in 1.70 ?
                boost_asio_handler_invoke_helpers::invoke(h, h);
            });
        },
        token, std::ref(service));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_async_wait_callback)
{
    boost::asio::io_context ioc;
    auto work = boost::asio::make_work_guard(ioc);

    callback_service service;

    boost::asio::spawn(ioc, [&] (boost::asio::yield_context yield) {
        const auto initiate_thread_id = std::this_thread::get_id();

        boost::asio::post(ioc, [&] {
            // call the completion handler from another thread.
            std::thread t([&] {
                service.run();
            });
            t.join();
        });

        async_wait_callback(service, yield);

        // Check if we resume in the correct execution context.
        BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(initiate_thread_id, std::this_thread::get_id());
        ioc.stop();
    });

    ioc.run();
}
```

The test code is failed with this error

```
Running 1 test case...
error: in "test_async_wait_callback": check initiate_thread_id == std::this_thread::get_id() has failed [10912 != 26444]
```

Which mean the stackful coroutine is not resume on the correct execution context.

Comment: My go-to resource on this topic is this article: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_io/writing_composed_operations.html
I think 1.70 made things fundamentally simpler and more flexible, but alas it's different. I'm highly interested in a well informed answer here.

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround is to dispatch the old callback via get_associated_executor.

```
template <typename CompletionToken>
auto async_wait_callback(callback_service& service, CompletionToken&& token)
{
    return boost::asio::async_initiate<CompletionToken, void(void)>(
        [] (auto&& completion_handler, callback_service& s) {
            s.subscribe([h=std::move(completion_handler)] () mutable {
                auto ex = boost::asio::get_associated_executor(h);
                boost::asio::dispatch(ex, [h=std::move(h)] () mutable {
                   boost_asio_handler_invoke_helpers::invoke(h, h);
                });
            });
        },
        token, std::ref(service));
}
```